# Asynchronous IE8/jquery table row height calculation

Tags: jquery, html-table, internet-explorer-8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test IE8 pre calc</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='inserthere'></div>
<p id="dump"></p>
<p id="dump2"></p>
</body>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
    var t = "<table style='white-space: pre;'><tr><td>abc def\nghi</td></tr></table>";

    $("#inserthere").append($(t));
    $("#dump").text($("tr").height());

    window.setTimeout(function () {
      $("#dump2").text($("tr").height());
    }, 0);
  });
</script>
</html>
```

In the code above I'm inserting a table to the DOM at runtime. The table is formatted using 'pre' white-space rules.

If `height()` of a row containing a multi-line td is calculated in the same call as the insertion IE8 incorrectly reports a single line (21 pixels). If the same call is made asynchronously IE8 correctly reports two lines (40 pixels).

IE9/10/Safari/Chrome/Firefox are fine.

Comment: Before the closing `</table>` there's a `<table>`, try removing that.

Comment: Sounds me to as if IE8 simply doesn't render it fast enough, though you seem to have already found the solution to that.

Comment: @Flauwekeul - well spotted. example fixed - but sadly not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a work around - so the answer is don't do it. white-space 'nowrap' works similarly once carriage returns are replaced with `<br>`.